# Use this curl command with Invoke-webrequest?

Tags: powershell, curl

I have this curl command:

```
curl -s -k -X POST https://xxxx/rest/com/vmware/cis/session -u 'xxx':'xxx'
```

How to convert this curl command to a powershell command?

Comment: Powershell has a built-in help system. Prefix  `Get-Help` before any cmdlet you want to know more about, so in your case: `Get-Help Invoke-Webrequest`. Also, curl.exe is available in windows given you're running win10

Answer (score 1):

As it seems, you are trying to connect vCenter server rest api, here's how:

```
$Credential = Get-Credential
$vCenterServer = 'vcenter-server'
$auth = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Credential.UserName+':'+$Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password))
$AuthHeader = @{
  'Authorization' = "Basic $auth"
}

$conn = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://$vCenterServer/rest/com/vmware/cis/session -Method Post -Headers $AuthHeader
```

Answer (score 1):

`Curl.exe` ships with Windows as of Windows 10 1803, so every server or Windows client since about March of 2018.

You can use it natively from PowerShell, but only when you specify the full executable name.

In other words

```
curl someurl.com      //uses the curl alias, which actually calls Invoke-WebRequest

curl.exe someurl.com //actually uses the real curl.exe binary.
```